# Unable to load Data in NavMenu

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

When I try to get values from Database for my NavMenu it seems that the values aren`t available fast enought.

NavMenu Html:

```
<h2>test</h2><h2>@titleList.Single(x => x.name == "test2").value</h2>
```

NavMenu code:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            titleList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<NavMenuStringModel>>("api/navMenuStrings");
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        List<NavMenuStringModel> navMenuStringModels = new List<NavMenuStringModel>()
        {
            new NavMenuStringModel(){name = "test2", value="test2"}
        };
        return Ok(navMenuStringModels);
    }
```

->Unhandelt exeption in Browser.
->Console shows  "No element is currently associated with component 8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't show it, I'm assuming titlelist is initialized as null.

So you probably need something like this:

```
<h2>test</h2>
@if(titlelist != null)
{
    <h2>titleList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.name == "test2").value</h2>    
}
```

I also suggest SingleOrDefault in case there is no matching element.

Finally you may need to call StateHasChanged() after you populate titlelist.